# You don't have permission to access a file on this server

Tags: php, apache, web, server, fedora

I use Apache under Fedora

My `httpd.conf` looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/tmp/meta>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I ran `sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/tmp/meta`, and when I try to access to `http://localhost/var/tmp/meta/my_file.json` I receive the error below:

> You don't have permission to access /var/tmp/meta/my_file.json on this server.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: The URL that you're trying to use to access the file is most probably not correct. Hard to tell without you seeing your apache config. Please edit your question and hopefully someone will be able to help.

Comment: I added some basic formatting to your question so it's easier to read. Please review [Stack Overflow's formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can do this yourself next time.

Comment: You normally don’t want a setup where the local file system root is fully exposed via HTTP. What does your virtual host look like, and what is the document root?

Comment: SELinux permissions. What are the AVC messages in the audit?

Answer (score -1):

Try this `chmod -R 777 /var/tmp/meta`

Comment: `chmod 777` is never a good idea if you care about safety *at all*